# How do I conditionally set variables in terraform 0.11.15

Tags: terraform

I am setting a variable:

```
variable "db_backup_enabled" {
  default = false
}
variable "db_backup_location" {}
```

My `main.tf` file looks like:

```
resource "aws_db_instance" "default" {
   backup_enabled  = ${var.db_backup_enabled}
   backup_location = ${var.db_backup_location}
}
```

I need to only set the `backup_location` in the resource if the `db_backup_enabled` is true, how can I do this?

The backup_location is an optional argument, so it should only be set if the other "backup_enabled" argument is true.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Terraform v0.11 and earlier do not have any way to dynamically decide whether or not to set an argument. Terraform v0.12 and later achieve this with the introduction of explicit `null` values, representing the absence of a value, but there is no equivalent concept in Terraform v0.11 and earlier.

The closest you can get to this in Terraform v0.11 and earlier is to consult the provider documentation to find out what is the default value for the argument -- that is, the value that the provider would use if the argument were unset -- and then set the argument explicitly to that value in the case where you want to provide the effect of it being unset.

This is not possible in all situations. For example, providers sometimes select default values dynamically in which case there may not be a specific value you can set that is equivalent to leaving the argument unset.

Terraform v0.11 is obsolete. You should upgrade to modern Terraform as soon as possible.

Comment: is the upgrade path for terraform seemless?  I am worried about the terraform state file!

Comment: Unfortunately because you've waited so long to upgrade there are [several steps required](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/v1.1.x/upgrade-guides/1-0) to reach modern Terraform. However, even just completing the upgrade from v0.11 to v0.12 will at least give you access to the `null` keyword. v0.12 is also obsolete, so I would recommend planning to continue upgrading eventually, but v0.12 is the minimum version you'll need to achieve what you asked in your question.